# How to create graphs for genetic algorithms

Tags: r

I'm working with the `ga` package and would like to create a few graphs based on the function below. `plot(GA)` seems to give a nice starting point, but I would like to create specific graphs such as

X Axis: Generation number

Y Axis: Best fitness

and

X Axis: Generation number

Y Axis: Average fitness

```r
library(GA)

cross <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {2 * x2 * x4 + x3 * ( x1 - 2 * x4)}

GA <- ga(type = "real-valued",
         fitness = function(x) -cross(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]),
         lower = c(10, 10, 0.9, 0.9), upper = c(80,50,5,5),
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 100, run = 100, pcrossover = 0.75, pmutation = .001)


summary(GA)
plot(GA)
```

Comment: @MrFlick While the function doesn't matter, all I'm trying to do is pull out the "average" and "best" from this plot and divide them into two graphs. https://imgur.com/a/m3GFeK8

Comment: If you gave us code that we can copy/paste to run to get that plot, then we can view the source code for the functions that drew the plot and help you extract the parts that you want.

Comment: @MrFlick I edited my post, I'm using RStudio and the version of the `GA` package that I have is 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the data out from the results via the `summary` slot of the object.

```
results <- as.data.frame(GA@summary)
results $iter = seq.int(nrow(results))
```

And then can use that to make your plots

```
plot(mean~iter, results)
plot(max~iter, results)
```